# Copy File and Create a Copy for Each in List Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to accomplish the task below in Python 3.7 (Juypter Notebook). My skill level is an absolute beginner so any help is greatly appreciated.

I have a file that I would like to copy and rename for each person that is assigned to employee_list + the current_month.

The file to copy is "Monthly Report.pdf". The desired outcome would be "Monthly Report - person1 - 0120.pdf", "Monthly Report - person2 - 0120.pdf".... for each person listed.

The code below creates 1 copy of the "Monthly Report.pdf" and renames it 'rpt_name'&'n'&'current_month'&'.pdf'

How can I adjust the code or is there a better way to do this task?

```
from shutil import copyfile

current_month = '0120'
rpt_name = 'Monthly Report -'
employee_list = ['person1', 'person2', 'person3']

for n in employee_list:
    copyfile('Monthly Report.pdf', "'rpt_name'&'n'&'current_month'&'.pdf'")
```

Answer (score 0):

The filenames of your copies are `"'rpt_name'&'n'&'current_month'&'.pdf'"` because what you have is a string literal. It's not looking for the values of those variables to put in the string.

What you're looking for is string interpolation. Try this instead.

```
from shutil import copyfile

current_month = '0120'
rpt_name = 'Monthly Report -'
employee_list = ['person1', 'person2', 'person3']

for n in employee_list:
    copyfile('Monthly Report.pdf', "{}{}{}.pdf".format(rpt_name, n, current_month))
```

There are many other ways to do this with strings in python. For example:

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation